# Amazon S3 and Spree setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, spree

Cant find a way for S3 to work with spree. There seem to exist few gems for that but dont seem to work for me.

Running rails 3.1.1 with spree 0.70.3.

Comment: what have you tried so far? and what errors are you encountering? Saying it doesn't work doesn't really help.

Comment: i have tried the followin gem https://github.com/dylanmei/spree-s3.git, or also https://github.com/thoughtful/spree-s3.git On both i get entity does not exist when i run rake spree_s3:install

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am running rails 3.0.10 and spree 0.60 and was able to get spree to use s3 storage over writing to the public folder of the app by doing the following The process should be alike.

add aws-s3 gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'aws-s3'
```

bundle installed and after doing that I created a yaml file in the config directory called s3.yml and it should look something like this.

```
development: &DEFAULTS
  bucket: "YOUR_BUCKET"
  access_key_id: "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
  secret_access_key: "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"

test:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
  bucket: "YOUR_BUCKET"

production:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
  bucket: "YOUR_BUCKET"
```

You can specify individual credentials per environment if you like but since mine are all using the same S3 accont I opted to set defaults.

after that you are going to have to override the image model or make a decorator for your  which tells paperclip to use S3 and to have it parse the yaml file created for credentials.

the area you want want to override would be this

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
                :styles => {:mini => '48x48>', :small => '200x100>', :product => '240x240>', :large => '600x600>'},
                :default_style => :small,
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                :url => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

you can change these properties as needed but whats important is that you specify :storage and :s3_credentials.

Comment: If you happen to bump Spree to newer version, for example 1.0.x, I'd recommend you to change the gem from `aws-s3` to `aws-sdk` because the former one is deprecated. Another quick way is to use spree-heroku extension https://github.com/joneslee85/spree-heroku.

If you go for Spree 1.1.x, you don't need to install any extension or override the model, you can configure that in the admin setting. Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of Spree, you can set these values in the admin tools. But if you prefer to maintain it in code **but without overriding the Image model**, you can set these values in config/initializers/spree.rb. Make sure not to edit them via the admin portal.

```
S3_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")[Rails.env]

Spree.config do |config|
  config.attachment_styles = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode({
        "mini" => "100x100>",
        "small" => "200x200>",
        "medium" => "400x600>",
        "product" => "400x600>",
        "large" => "600x600>",
        "xl" => "800x800>",
        "xxl" => "1200x1200>",

    })

   #AWS S3
  config.use_s3 = true
  config.s3_bucket = S3_CONFIG['bucket']
  config.s3_access_key = S3_CONFIG['access_key_id']
  config.s3_secret = S3_CONFIG['secret_access_key']
  config.attachment_url = 'products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
  config.attachment_path = 'products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the BitNami Spree AMIs at http://bitnami.org/stack/spree. Regards.